# Rails 5 Not Raising Error with self.errors.add(:base)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model called `Thing` and a controller called `Things`.

I followed [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923125/in-rails-how-to-limit-users-post-count-saved-in-database-before-asking-to-upgrad) to try and set a maximum amount of `Things` a user can create.

Here's the warning: the terminal is giving a warning (not a huge issue) of `DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing an argument to force an association to reload is now deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Please call "reload" on the result collection proxy instead.` What should I do to make it go away?

Here's the problem: The line `self.errors.add(:base, "Exceeded Things Limit")` isn't displaying an alert or notice in the view. How would I achieve this? It's not creating a new Thing (because I met the maximum limit of 2) which is good, but it's just reloading a new form which would be horrible for user experience.

I'm working Rails 5 and Devise.

Here's my `Thing` model:

```
class Thing < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 validate :thing_count_within_limit, :on => :create
 attr_accessor :validation_code, :flash_notice

 def self.search(search)
      if search
           where("zipcode LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
      else
           all
      end
 end

 def thing_count_within_limit
      if self.user.things(:reload).count >= 2
           self.errors.add(:base, "Exceeded Things Limit")
      end
 end
end
```

And here's my `Things` controller:

```
class thingsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :find_thing, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 before_action :authenticate_user_first, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
 before_action :authorized_pilot, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy, :profile]

 def index
      @things = Thing.all.order("created_at ASC")
      @things = Thing.search(params[:search])
 end

 def new
      @thing = current_user.things.build
 end

 def create
      @thing = current_user.things.build(thing_params)
      if @thing.save
           redirect_to @thing
      else
           render "new"
      end
 end

 def profile
      @things = Thing.where(user_id: current_user)
 end

 def show
 end

 def edit
 end

 def update
      if @thing.update(thing_params)
           redirect_to @thing
      else
           render "edit"
      end
 end

 def destroy
      if @thing.destroy
           redirect_to root_path
      else
           redirect_to @thing
      end
 end

 private
      def thing_params
           params.require(:thing).permit(:title, :description, :image).merge(zipcode: current_user.zipcode)
      end

      def find_thing
           @thing = thing.find(params[:id])
      end

      def authenticate_user_first
           if current_user != thing.find(params[:id]).user
                redirect_to @thing
           else
           end
      end
 end
```

Can anyone help? Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you give `if self.user.things.count >= 2`?

Comment: @Pavan - Thanks! That got rid of the terminal error. I still need it to create an alert from the model (or at least pass it into the controller and that can raise the alert). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that aren't connected to each other.

First, there is the deprecation warning. Because it is just a warning, not an error, you can choose to ignore it at the moment. If you want to remove the warning, just follow its instruction and change this line

```
if self.user.things(:reload).count >= 2
```

to

```
self.user.things.reload.count >= 2
```

Seconds, your code works like expected. Rails validations do not raise any errors, but they add error messages to the object. Just make sure that you display the errors to the user. To display the error you added to `:base`, add something like the following to your `new.html.erb` view:

```
<% if @thing.errors[:base].any? %>
  <div class="error_message">
    <%= @thing.errors.full_messages_for(:base).to_sentence %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks @spickerman! It worked like a charm! How could I add it to the rails <%= alert %> method though?

Comment: You would have to assign (copy) the errors to it. `alert = @thing.errors.full_messages_for(:base).to_sentence`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Do you mean doing <%= alert = @thing.errors.full_messages_for(:base).to_sentence %> or is it something I would do in the model or controller?

Comment: You could do that in the controller right before the `render "new"` line. Do you have code in place to show `alert` messages to the user?

Comment: Yes I do, but it's in the application controller. In your answer with the `if` statement, it just adds a paragraph tag to the document. I want it to be added as an <%= alert %> so it's styled the way I have it in my stylesheet. How would I do this?

Comment: Without knowing your code and how you handle `alerts` I can only guess. I would say that could be done exactly like I wrote above...

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out. I just needed to put my CSS divs around the alert. It's working now. Thanks a lot!